# How Does Windows Pick memory for threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, heap-memory

My previous post,**(Edit: Now solved)**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470978/new-thread-corrupting-string-data-c 
was too complicated it seems. So this is a more general post to answer my questions.

If a thread is created inside a If, For, while, case, ect. Is the thread's heap a sub set of the memory allocated for the control statement? If so is there a way to choose where in memory the new thread is created? Thank you.
(Windows 7, Visual Studio 2013, C++ )

Another question I have: 
 [Mutex not correctly used? Continuation of past questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489891/mutex-not-correctly-used-continuation-of-past-questions)

Comment: if you think your old question is too complicated don't make us read it, please formulate a complete new question here

Comment: I do not feel it is complicated, it has been flagged by mods. I have linked it for reference only. My question is appended by a "?" for easy reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ... the thread shares memory with the main thread and all other threads started by the app.  That is what makes multi-threading more difficult.  You have to be careful when multiple threads access the same memory.

Threads all share the same resources but only the main thread can interact with the GUI.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Do you know of a call to allocate memory for a particular thread? My issue is the child thread is being created over data made by the parent thread.

Comment: That should not be possible. How are you checking that the data is overwritten ?

Comment: I have a LPTSTR point to a string in memory , I have created a watch for this Pointer. As i step through my code, the strings value ( At the address the pointer points to) changes from L"Features_30_34_40.bmp" to a bunch of unicode characters. I used the memory window of Visual studio and the new thread is being created over the strings data. You can see in memory the string and then you can see it get changed.

Comment: It seems strange.. and quite hard to solve without some code ! Can you try to cut your code up to 10 lines that can reproduce the error ?

Comment: in sudo the code looks like:

`Make a thread; 
    Pass a message to parent thread;
    Kill thread;
Mainthread takes message and makes a string;
    Make a new thread and pass this new string;
`
I will take some time to write a short program that represents this in c++

Comment: That shared pool also makes threading easier at the same time. You don't have to use interprocess communication to pass information between threads. @ChrisEst most of the problem with the earlier question was you dropped a large ball of code. You need to post the minimal compilable code that triggers your error. What you posted was neither minimal or compilable. There is nothing brutally obvious, so amount of fill-in-the-blanks guesswork that needed to go into formulating an answer made trying to answer the question pretty much impossible.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for your clarifying where my last post went wrong. Today I will try to reproduce this problem with shorter code. 

Is there any answer to " Can I tell where a thread should be made in memory?"

Comment: I don't think so, and it should not be necessary. Your system should be able to do it proprely without overwriting the important variables.

Comment: I have edited the main post to include some code. After writing this code it may be my mutexes causing the issue.

Comment: @ChrisEst Each thread has it's own stack, defaults to 1 MB on Windows as I recall, and so long as you stay within that pool, you're fine. But you are actively sharing data, your message structure, between multiple threads. Not a good idea and mutex can only protect you from two or more threads accessing a variable at the same time within guarded regions. It cannot protect you from one thread entering a guarded region and changing a value to a value not expected by another thread or any access from outside a guarded region. Also, don't change the question. Ask a new one.

Comment: Ok thats good to know. 1MB will not be enough for the thread as some images it will open will be around 100MB. What would be the name of the tool that I can implement to stop a thread from over flowing into a guarded region if a mutex can not do this?

Comment: @ChrisEst, if you have data that's going to require massive amounts of storage, odds are they are going to be dynamically allocated, and if they aren't it'll be pretty easy to force them. As for the mutex, it is an agreement. It's like asking for permission to walk across your neighbour's lawn and waiting until you get it. No one forces you to ask, and someone who doesn't ask has no way to know that the lawn is a restricted area. If everyone but one user acquires the mutex before accessing a variable, that one user can still ruin things for everyone.

Comment: @ChrisEst the next problem is it only protects against multiple accesses at the same time. Thread B can acquire the mutex, change the value, and release the value before thread A can, and if B has changed the value that A was expecting to get, sucks to be A.

Comment: That's a good way to put it. In my separate thread one user suggested that i have a message handler. i.e. a gate for the lawn.  The handler will only have the mutex and release information if its available. So if a thread asks the handler it will be blocked until a message is released, taking away the protection job from the thread and having a separate system to do it.