# Mutex not correctly used? Continuation of past questions

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a second question that is a continuation of this thread :  [How Does Windows Pick memory for threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487064/how-does-windows-pick-memory-for-threads)

```
void ThreadTest(LPTSTR* Pointer, mutex* MutexPtr)
{
    MutexPtr->lock();   
    wcout << *Pointer << endl;
    MutexPtr->unlock();
    return;
}
void FakeMain()
{
    mutex Mut;
    mutex* MutPtr = &Mut;
    LPTSTR Image = L"First String";
    LPTSTR* StrPointer = &Image;
    thread Test(ThreadTest, StrPointer, MutPtr);
    MutPtr->lock();
    if (true)
    {

        NewStringFunction(Image);
        MutPtr-unlock() // Added with the comment of Mike
        Test.join();        
        LPTSTR* StrPointer = &Image;        
        thread Test(ThreadTest, StrPointer, MutPtr);                
    }

    MutPtr->lock();
    Test.join();
    MutPtr->unlock();
    return;
};
void NewStringFunction(LPTSTR& Image)
{
    LPTSTR TempString = L"New String for new Thread";
    Image = TempString;
    return;
};
```

The Code above is emulates my code I am having issues with.
 The flow should be as follows:

- The FakeMain() initialized variables and sets a String;
- FakeMain then creates a thread for this string to be printed.
- New thread prints the string.
- The printing thread is destroyed and a new string is made by a separate external function.
- A new thread is made to print this new message

I have an "if" statement because the real code has a thread being made inside an if statement, i wanted to make sure the memory allocation represented this.
The string is changed in a separate function because this is how the real code does this.
I destroy the first thread because in the real code, the thread is displaying a window, which changes size, thus needs a new thread.

From writing this code I feel my mutexs are not implemented correctly. This code is not giving string errors but I think the mutex is being over written by the thread (i think). Watching the memory as the program runs, the first thread instance may over write the mutex, I am not sure. The last mutex.lock() in the main thread is throwing an error. Am I using mutexes correctly? Is there a cleaner way I should be locking/stopping threads?

Comment: What *exactly* is this code supposed to be *doing* ? You never said *exactly* what the desired workflow is, nor why you're doing any of this in the first place. This immediately contains a race to latch the mutex (the thread and main). It is entirely possible the `Test ` thread will acquire the mutex, perform the output, release the mutex and return before you ever even reach the subsequent  `MutPtr->lock();` in `FakeMain`. Further, if that *doesn't* happen, you lock the mutex *twice* in main, then try to join the thread, which will wait for a lock it can never acquire.

Comment: The desired out put should have the thread print one message. The message is then being changed by an external function, then a new thread is made to print this new message. I do notice the "race" to lock the mutex, this is where I think my program is error-ed. How can i fix this without adding a "Sleep(50);" statement?

Comment: Given the workflow in your question, there should never be a time when both threads are "running". And since the resource you're trying to protect is never modified concurrently (again, with your workflow, that includes any thread(s) and even `main()`), I don't understand the reason for a mutex in *any* of this. Why can't you just do [something like this](http://pastebin.com/cvqdALNy) ?

Comment: The mutex is for other data structures that is not in this code, I have a msg class in the real code that is passed and edited by both threads. I understand with this simple program mutexes, even threading, is unnecessary, was just representing what my real code does. The editing of a string is what was giving my real code errors so i tryed to represent it here. I have since figured out ( i think) my original problem, which was the new LPTSTR being made by the external function was going out of scope as FakeMain() returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a mutex and don't share the memory.

Brute force approach:

All the sender needs to do is

```
Message msg = new Message(<important information>);
// send msg
```

And in the receiving code,

```
// use msg  
delete msg;
```

Very simple to write and use, but has a memory leak: if a message never gets serviced, it never gives back the RAM.

Better versions can get very complicated. Here is an outline for a simple one:

```
Create a pool of Messages
Assign all messages to a FreeList
Create a mutex to protect FreeList
```

FreeList is a list of messages that are not currently being used. When a Message needs to be sent, the first Message is removed from FreeList and handed to the caller. The caller fills out Message with the information to be sent and then sends the Message.

The receiver is responsible for returning the Message to FreeList .

Add a few functions to manage FreeList

```
GetMsg <changed to prevent collision with Windows GetMessage function>
    Message = NULL
    acquire mutex
    if FreeList not empty
        remove Message from FreeList
    release mutex
    return message            

ReturnMsg
    acquire mutex
    Add Message to FreeList
    release mutex
```

Sender is a bit more complicated

```
Message msg = GetMessage()
If msg not NULL
    msg.set(<important information>);
    std::thread temp(ThreadTest, msg);
    temp.detatch
else
    // log and handle <- can be simple like abort or complicated like recover lost Messages
```

And receiver is still pretty simple

```
// use msg  
ReturnMessage(msg);
```

This has a cap on the memory leak and can make it easy to track which Messages never got returned (in pool, but not in FreeList) so you can attempt to track down which jobs got blocked or blown up. Fixing the lock or blow-up is another problem.

OP had a good idea that I think I have about right. Here are the guts of a basic thread function. It hangs out in the background running until sent a terminate message. It blocks waiting for a message, consumes the message, and then puts it back in FreeList and blocks until another message arrives.

```
void threadfunc()
{
    MSG winmsg;
    BOOL rval;

    while (GetMessage(&winmsg, (HWND__ *) -1, 0, 0) != -1)
    {
        Message * msg = (Message *)winmsg.wParam;
        // do stuff with msg
        ReturnMsg(msg);
    }
    // GetMessage failed. Find out why and try to recover or die gracefully
}
```

It needs to be supported by something like

```
bool PostMsg(<Important Information>,
             DWORD & BackgroundThreadId)
{
    Message * msg = GetMsg();
    if (msg != NULL)
    {
         msg.set(<Important Information>)
        if (PostThreadMessage(BackgroundThreadId,
                              WM_USER,
                              (WPARAM) msg,
                              0); != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // failed. Find out why and try to recover or die gracefully
            ReturnMsg(msg);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // out of free messages. Try to find out why
    }
}
```

PostMsg feeds Messages into the background thread's message queue. Messages come from the FreeList and only the FreeList needs mutex protection. More than one thread can be in use. <s>I don't think this can be done with std::thread since std::thread doesn't give access to the underlying thread handle</s> (Just checked, it can be done)  or the thread's message queue. It'as all based on Windows calls anyway, so forget about portability.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for your time.

 If i understand correctly, your putting the messages into a FIFO type container. Then only modifying (popping from the FIFO) them when the mutex is unlocked. So the FIFO list never gets edited directly but only the message popped is getting edited. The mutex is not shared with the 2 threads but for the message handler only, the handler will say if the Get_MSG() can have a message or not. The threads will call Get_MSG() and will return when a message is available.

Comment: The delete of the message is something i have looked over. If the message is a LPTSTR, would changing the LPTSTR essentially free the old string it originally pointed to?

Comment: @ChrisEst Misinterpretation, but your interpretation sounds like a good way to run your task like a thread pool. I was concerned only with making certain that each thread got a guaranteed unique message that another thread can't overwrite. Let me see if I can clear that up.

Comment: Thank you so very much for putting the time in to answer my question. Your code also explains some API question I had with threading too. This is a much cleaner way of doing it , I will implement this into my program. +1.

Comment: @ChrisEst Not a problem. I'll be rewriting some old windows threading code now that I dug up how to do it better.

Answer (score 1):

The lock call before the if statement does not have a matching unlock.
Also you have a potential deadlock if the main thread gets the mutex before the test thead. Also your last join is waiting on the wrong thread. As far as I can tell there is no reason to lock the mutex to do the join. Just do the join.

Comment: You are correct! I will edit the code to fix this. Thank you.