# C++ multi-threaded algorithm design for notify-wait pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm looking for an advice and code samples of a multi-threaded implementation on Windows of the following algo:

- Thread1: Take `input1`, do work, notify `Thread2`, continue work.
- Thread2: Take `input2`, do work, wait for notification from thread2, do some processing, notify `Thread3`, continue work.
- Thread3: Take `input3`, do work, wait for notification from thread3, do some processing, notify `Thread4`, continue work.
  etc..

Since I'm novice to C++, I'm not sure what mechanism to choose to send/receive notification between threads.
I considered several approaches: `mutex`, `semaphore`, `critical section`, but these seem for locking mostly, not for wait-notify.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, so far.

Comment: If you are on windows, consider using [Windows Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Using Windows events would be incredibly slow!  Just use a simple boolean, protected with a mutex, that's all that is needed.

Comment: @ravenspoint It's not all that slow, probably overkill for what he wants though.

Comment: A mutex would be overkill here as well. Use an atomic bool instead. Also an atomic has its cost, but is much more lightweight.

Comment: He needs something waitable, so neither an atomic bool nor a bool protected by a mutex will do what he wants.

Comment: By the way, the design suggested in the question where specific threads wait for specific events is basically an anti-pattern. Rather than thinking "I need a thread to wait for this to happen and then do something" think "when this thing happens, I need to do something". You don't need a specific thread waiting for a specific thing -- that just forces extra context switches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the usual helpers you already listed you should take a look at [condition variable](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

> The condition_variable class is a synchronization primitive that can
>   be used to block a thread, or multiple threads at the same time,
>   until:
>       - a notification is received from another thread
>       [...]

When a condition variable is used, thread 2 can wait until it was `notified' so thread 2 can continue and so on. Here is a simple example:

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
static bool ready = false;

static void set ()
{
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    while (!ready)
      cv.wait(lck);
  }

  std::cout << "message received" << std::endl;
}

static void go()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  ready = true;

  // here we set the condition variable for thread1
  cv.notify_all();
}

int main ()
{
  std::thread thread1 = std::thread(set);

  go();
  thread1.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say each thread's task function looks something like this:

```
void threadfunc()
{
    MSG winmsg;
    BOOL rval;

    while (GetMessage(&winmsg, (HWND__ *) -1, 0, 0) != -1)
    {
        DoThreadProcessing();
    }
    // GetMessage failed. Find out why and try to recover or die gracefully
}
```

This blocks on [GetMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) until the thread is woken by the arrival of a message sent by this next function

```
bool PostMsg(DWORD & ThreadId)
{
    if (PostThreadMessage(ThreadId,
                          WM_USER,
                          (WPARAM) NULL,
                          0); != 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // failed. Find out why and try to recover or die gracefully
        return false;
    }
}
```

through the magic of [PostThreadMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you care what sort of message is sent, you can send simple information like a number in the `Msg` parameter and pull it from `winmsg.message`. Keep the number small because Windows uses the upper half of `message` for it's own nefarious purposes.

If you need more complex messaging, [Mutex not correctly used? Continuation of past questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489891/mutex-not-correctly-used-continuation-of-past-questions/30491259#30491259) covers this.

So in the OP's case, thread 1 calls PostMsg with thread 2's handle to wake thread 2. Thread 2 calls PostMsg with thread 3's handle and so on.

You may even be able to use [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)'s [native_handle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) method to stay mostly within the standard library, but I've never tested this. Let me know if it works.