# C++: Control order of thread execution with mutex's and conditional variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

This question is a follow up for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468325/c-multi-threaded-algorithm-design-for-notify-wait-pattern). I want threads to perform some work and pass handle to the next thread in order. When trying to execute the following code, I get

*Unhandled exception at 0x0F7C1F5F (msvcp120d.dll) in ConsoleApplication9.exe: 0xC0000005 : Access violation reading location 0x00000004.*

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <condition_variable> 

    std::mutex* m_pMutexs;
    std::condition_variable* m_pCVs;
    int m_pCurrentWorker;

    void func(int i)
    {
        int cvCurrentInd = i;
        std::mutex* pCurMutex = &m_pMutexs[cvCurrentInd];

        std::condition_variable* pCuCV = (std::condition_variable*)(m_pCurrentWorker + i*sizeof(std::condition_variable));

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_pMutexs[i]);

        while (i != m_pCurrentWorker)
        {
            pCuCV->wait(lk);
        }

        std::cout << "entered thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(rand() % 10));
        std::cout << "leaving thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

        m_pCurrentWorker++;
        lk.unlock();
        pCuCV->notify_one();

    }

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        m_pMutexs = new std::mutex[3];

        m_pCVs = new std::condition_variable[3];

        m_pCurrentWorker = 0;

        srand((unsigned int)time(0));

        std::thread t1(func,0);
        std::thread t2(func,1);
        std::thread t3(func,2);

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want that? Why does it seem that everyone wants to use threads that totally defeat the point of having threads.

Comment: No lock protects `m_pCurrentWorker`. Also, threads are notifying themselves, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: There is no need to protect m_pCurrentWorker, since by design only 1 thread can change it. Each thread notifies the next thread.

Comment: You are wrong. It needs to be protected. Any time an object may get modified by one thread while another thread is, or might be, accessing it, protection is needed. This is a *serious* mistake that will cause your code to fail.

Comment: m_pCurrentWorker is protected by the unique lock on mutex and the condit. variable. The CV allows to change m_pCurrentWorker only one thread at a time -- the thread that has (i == m_pCurrentWorker).

Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: `m_pCurrentWorker` is a single variable that exists in only one instance. Yet each thread that touches it uses a different lock. Thus no lock prevents conflict. Each thread can have its own lock and access `m_pCurrentWorker` while it's being changed. This creates the very race that you are using the condition variable to prevent!

Comment: Condition variables exist for one reason, to provide an atomic "unlock and wait" operation that protects against a race where you take a lock, decide to wait, release the lock, and then wait, but after you released the lock and before you waited, the thing you were waiting for already happened, so you're waiting for something that has already happened. Avoiding this race is the sole purpose of condition variables, and by not protecting the shared state properly, you've re-introduced this very race!

Comment: "Yet each thread that touches it uses a different lock." Yes, but only one thread can change m_pCurrentWorker at a time -- the one that has (i == m_pCurrentWorker)

The rest of threads are blocked and wait because of this statement:
while (i != m_pCurrentWorker)
        {
            pCuCV->wait(lk);
        }

With that said, can you suggest a better code sample to handle it?

Comment: I can't tell if you understand my point. Do you see why the failure to have a single lock that protects `m_pCurrentWorker` makes the while loop not work? (It's neither holding nor releasing the lock that protects the shared state its testing!) The correct solution is to use a single lock to protect shared state, not many different locks protecting the very same object.

Comment: I understand your point, but I'm not sure you understand mine. The main purpose of the while loop is not to lock/release a resource, but to block execution of the current thread until it's notified by the prev. thread. Do you agree that the current thread will not execute after the while loop until it's notified?
I posted the working code below. You are welcome to play with it and ensure that it works.

Comment: No, I don't agree. You have a race condition that could lead to missed wakeups and deadlock. You've used condition variables in an unsafe way by not protecting the shared state properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89977/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-andrew-lewis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have no idea what you're trying to do but

You're casting integer to pointer?

```
std::condition_variable* pCuCV = (std::condition_variable*)(m_pCurrentWorker + i*sizeof(std::condition_variable));
```

I think you should write instead:

```
std::condition_variable* pCuCV = &m_pCVs[i];
```

The whole function could be something like this:

```
void func(int i)
{
    std::mutex* pCurMutex = &m_pMutexs[i];

    std::condition_variable* pCuCV = &m_pCVs[i];

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_pMutexs[i]);

    while (i != m_pCurrentWorker) {
        pCuCV->wait(lk);
    }

    std::cout << "entered thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(rand() % 2));
    std::cout << "leaving thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    m_pCurrentWorker++;
    lk.unlock();
    if (m_pCurrentWorker > 2) {
        return;
    }
    pCuCV = &m_pCVs[m_pCurrentWorker];
    pCuCV->notify_one();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some further research and it seems that the code the original questions is not thread-safe