# C++ ensure that threads change common resource in certain order

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

This is a follow up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535394/c-control-order-of-thread-execution-with-mutexs-and-conditional-variables). I'm trying to ensure that a common resource (m_pCurrentWorker) is changed in certain order by multiple threads. I'm using a mutex and conditional variable per thread, and in the end of a thread execution, I notify conditional variable of the next thread in order to continue. The working code is below, and I ran it dozens of time and always get correct order of execution and there are seem to be no deadlocks:

```
entered thread 0
leaving thread 0
entered thread 1
leaving thread 1
entered thread 2
leaving thread 2
```

Yet, there is discussion below the original question that this implementation is wrong. Would be nice to hear other people's opinion about this design and suggestions to improve it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable> 

std::mutex* m_pMutexs;
std::condition_variable* m_pCVs;
int m_pCurrentWorker;

void func(int i)
{
    std::mutex* pCurMutex = &m_pMutexs[i];

    std::condition_variable* pCuCV = &m_pCVs[i];

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_pMutexs[i]);

    while (i != m_pCurrentWorker)
    {
        pCuCV->wait(lk);
    }

    std::cout << "entered thread " << i << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(rand() % 2));
    std::cout << "leaving thread " << i << std::endl;

    m_pCurrentWorker++;
    lk.unlock();
    if (m_pCurrentWorker > 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    pCuCV = &m_pCVs[m_pCurrentWorker];
    pCuCV->notify_one();

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    m_pMutexs = new std::mutex[3];

    m_pCVs = new std::condition_variable[3];

    m_pCurrentWorker = 0;

    srand((unsigned int)time(0));

    std::thread t1(func, 0);
    std::thread t2(func, 1);
    std::thread t3(func, 2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll likely get a better result over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As pointed out in the comments on your previous question, what you're trying to achieve completely defeats the point of having multiple threads.

Comment: @mattnewport has a very good point. Have you considered a state machine instead?

Comment: I disagree. Imagine that threads do some work in parallel, and then in the middle/end of execution each thread needs to ensure that previous thread completed and changed the common resource. Running this logic in single thread is much slower.

Comment: If you have a situation where you have multiple pieces of independent expensive work, each producing a cheap result that must then be used to modify some shared state in a specific order, then why not just have a main thread wait on the results of all the expensive operations and then sequentially apply the state changes?

Comment: The code above is a simplification of the algo, I'm working on. In the original algo, each thread has a sequence of expensive pieces and after each piece it should notify the next thread. The second thread does the same, notifies 3rd thread, etc. This is briefly explained in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468325/c-multi-threaded-algorithm-design-for-notify-wait-pattern)

Comment: I'm going to stick with the message passing and task queue I suggested last time. By the way, *infinite* successful runs is insufficient to prove thread synchronization correctness. It only proves that you didn't test a failure case. You need to test all possible failure cases (good luck with that) or formally prove that failure is impossible.

Comment: @user4581301, I appreciate your suggestion, but I would rather keep the code I have, unless it's wrong, which I don't believe it is.

Comment: @user4581301, and I think that mutex/CV are more low-level and faster.

Comment: Not a problem. In this case I will recommend wrapping a single mutex, a single condition var, and a func in a class and only maintaining a pointer to the class. Easier to clean up and should also eliminate the need for i.

Comment: But this: `while (this != m_pCurrentWorker)` will prevent the other threads from running while the current thread is running and that reverts the algorithm back to a monothread. You're going to have to rethink that. Are the threads intended to be one use and discard?

Comment: @user4581301. Thanks! In my actual algo, thread do a lot of work before coming to this part: while (this != m_pCurrentWorker). I'm using threadpool and recycle threads.

Comment: @AndrewLewis I still think you're approaching the design wrong but currently standard C++ doesn't offer the right tools out of the box to easily implement a better design. You'd be better off using something like Microsoft's PPL / Intel's TBB but that is not (yet) standardized.

Comment: I've poked at this for a while now. This given case  is hard to break because it is serial behaviour in multiple threads, but it also won't survive parallel behaviour. If a thread C waits after the signal from thread B, thread C will not wake until thread B signals again. If thread B's next signal is dependent on thread C, game over. Either way, B and C are no longer synchronized. David Schwartz warned of this in the previous thread. You need a synchronization primitive with memory so that it won't block if a trigger is pending. You already know what I'll suggest.

Comment: @user4581301 what you say is reasonable, but my design and implementation is A -> B -> C -> A ->...
Threads execute consecutively. So, there should not be deadlocks or races.

Comment: And that rolls back to the start of the discussion. If the threads operate consecutively you gain nothing from threading A, B, and C. if A can be processing dataset N+2 while B is processing stage 2 of N+1 and C is processing stage 3 of N, you have a case for threading. But this opens you up for the possibility that B will finish N+1 and signal C before C has finished N and begun waiting on the signal from B.